# for all and for every , what's wrong with this simple contradiction?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, logic, real-numbers

For these two statements,
(1). There exists a positive real number $\dfrac {\varepsilon } {2}$
    smaller than every  positive real number $ {\varepsilon } $ .

(2). There is no positive real number smaller than every  positive real
        number $ {\varepsilon } $ .

Questions :

1. (1) contradicts with (2),  which is wrong and which is right ?
2. What I got confused to get this contradiction?

Comment: (1) doesn't make much sense. If you say "there exists...", then you implicitly assume that the number $\varepsilon/2$ is fixed, and hence so is $\varepsilon$, so you can't really say that this then holds for all $\varepsilon$.

Comment: In order for (1) to contradict (2), it would need to establish a positive number (not an expression) that is smaller than every positive real number.  What number would that be?  $\varepsilon/2$?  That's not smaller than $\varepsilon/4$, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of your logical symbols is important.

1. For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a smaller real number. 
   $$
   \forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0 \text{ such that } \delta<\epsilon
   $$
2. There does not exists a number that is smaller for all $\epsilon>0$. 
   $$
   \nexists \delta > 0 \forall \epsilon>0 \text{ such that } \delta<\epsilon
   $$

Note that these statements don't contradict eachother. Actually, they are the same statement. Call the second statement $A$. Then $A = (A^c)^c$.

\begin{align}
A^c &= \exists \delta > 0 \forall \epsilon>0 \text{ such that } \delta<\epsilon. \\
(A^c)^c &= \forall\delta > 0 \exists\epsilon>0 \text{ such that } \delta>\epsilon
\end{align}
This is the same as statement 1 with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ reversed.

Comment: Then how to tell the order of logical symbols in a statement ?

Comment: @iMath The author should make that clear, by making the order of the *sentence* follow the order of the *symbols*: e.g. they should have written "For every $\epsilon>0$ there is a positive real smaller than $\epsilon$". In certain cases, a failure to do so is okay when there are other textual clues. For example, in the statement (1) above, "there exists a positive real number ${\epsilon\over 2}$" references $\epsilon$, so must come *after* the quantifier introducing $\epsilon$. This is, however, pretty bad writing, and I find the language of statement (1) fairly unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The subtlety here fooled me once to.

The key to understanding the contradiction is noticing what is fixed first.

For *"There exists a positive real number $\dfrac {\varepsilon } {2}$
    smaller than every  positive real number $ {\varepsilon } $ "* we first set $\epsilon $, any epsilon, and then say $\dfrac {\varepsilon } {2}$ is smaller, which is true.

For *"There is no positive real number smaller than every  positive real
        number $ {\varepsilon } $"* we are saying that, there is no number that we can fix that will be smaller than any other. They are saying that whatever, for how many small, $x $ is, there will be a smaller $\epsilon $.